# What's this service on macOS 12.3?

Tags: mac, monterey, daemons

What is this service /usr/libexec/remotepairingdeviced??

```
NMAP
PORT      STATE SERVICE
49152/tcp open  unknown

lost -i :49152
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd      1 root   13u  IPv6 0xe6318e44a459c0dd      0t0  TCP *:49152 (LISTEN)
remotepai 1121 root    3u  IPv6 0xe6318e44a459c0dd      0t0  TCP *:49152 (LISTEN)

sudo ps xuwww -p 1121
root  1121   0.0  0.1 408230064   8464   ??  Ss    2:22PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/remotepairingdeviced
```

Comment: I only found this: https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/remotepairingdeviced.1.html which I guess is the same as `man remotepairingdeviced`.

Comment: Did macOS create a firewall rule for this service automatically for you? Only noticed it after I updated and seen a blocking incoming connections rule had been added.

Comment: I did not check the firewall, time to time I nmap my networks (Devices) and noticed this service on first i thought it was trojan or something like that. 
Therefore, no rule was added on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its `man` page, it's:

```
DESCRIPTION
 A service that manages remote pairing.
```

So it's for managing the pairing of an Apple Remote. (Possibly other Bluetooth paired devices.)
In short: it's harmless and should be left alone.

Comment: I think you need to explain "remote pairing".

Comment: I wouldn’t mix the streams @Gilby simple answer to a simple question works best IMO. It would be better to ask what does this do as a new question so proper answers can be provided

Comment: Indeed that's what I wanted to know.